# I have a question with "Intoduction to analysis, fourth edition" by Wade, theorem 6.40.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, estimation

I have a question with the theorem 6.40 ii) from the book "Introduction to Analysis, fourth edition", which is written by Wade.
[Theorem 6.40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvEhg.png)

I think if $k>N$, $|a_{N + 1}| \leq |a_ N| \times x$ cannot be established, so I think it should be $k \geq N$.

So I want to know that am I right.

If I'm wrong, please explain the reason to me.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems that you didn't gave us all the details, what is s ?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I editted the image Theorem 6.40.

Comment: I recently editted some wrong things... Not < but $\leq$, and not n but N.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in (0,1)$ and $s= \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k|$ for reals $a_k$. Further, for $k> N$, $|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|<x$.

Prove $0\le s - \sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|\le \frac{|a_N|x^{n-N+1}}{1-x} \forall n\ge N$.

I think $k\ge N$ works in part because it includes $k>N$. I think he defined it that way to save you a step.

By hypothesis, $|\frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}|<x$. So$ |a_{N+1}|<x|a_N|<|a_N|$.

We also have by similar arguments $|a_{N+2}|<x|a_{N+1}|<|a_{N+1}|$.

Combined, these imply $|a_{N+2}|<x^2|a_N|$, and more generally, $|a_{N+k}|<x^k|a_N|$.

Thus it follows $|a_N|+|a_{N+1}|+|a_{N+2}|+...\le \frac{|a_N|}{1-x}$

Similary, by  hypothesis, this holds for any $n>N$, so$ |a_n|+|a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+2}|+...\le \frac{|a_n|}{1-x}$

We also have by above arguments that $|a_n|<x^{n-N}|a_N|$

So $s\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k|+\frac{|a_N|x^{n-N}}{1-x}$

Use $n+1$ inplace of n instead, and subtract the sigma expression from both sides, we get:

$s-\sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|\le \frac{|a_N|x^{n-N+1}}{1-x}$

Comment: Could $|a_{N+1}|<x|a_{N}|$ can be established? Because if $|a_{N+1}|<x|a_{N}|$ is established, $k$ should be $N$ but in condition, $k>N$. That's the point what I'm confusing...

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. The question which was $|a_{n+1}| < |a_{n}| \times x$ should be $|a_{N+1}| \leq |a_{N}| \times x$.

Answer (score 0):

I Think I'm right. For example, if
$$a_k = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if k = 1}\\
    (1/3)^k & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},$$
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {a_k}=1/6$(absolute converge). And if $k>N=1$,
$$\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_{k}|} \leq \frac{1}{3} .$$
Meanwhile, $s-\sum_{k=1}^{1} {a_k} = 1/6 - 0 = 1/6$ and
$$\frac{|a_N|x^{n-N+1}}{1-x} = 0$$
so,$$s-\sum_{k=1}^{1} {a_k} > \frac{|a_N|x^{n-N+1}}{1-x} .$$
So, I think it should be fixed to $k\geq N$.

Comment: This should be an edit to your question.